# Get Resource Calendar with Directory API

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

I really tried but can't figure it out by myself how to retrieve the data of a resource calendar with the Directory API.

**What I want:**

- retrieve the data of my company's resource calendar by using a service account with domain-wide delegation

**What I have:**

- service account with domain-wide delegation (+ credentials.json)
- calendar ID of my company's resource calendar

I'm a non-admin user and as far as I know the service account has to impersonate a user.
Do I need to be an admin user to manage and see the data of the resource calendar and share it with the service account?
I use a jwtClient to authorize and I have no idea whether I have to use the Directory API, Google Calendar API or both to make it work.

I tried to use the Google Calendar API first but it didn't work and now I guess I have to get the resource calendar with the Directory API.
That's what I have so far:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

let {google} = require('googleapis');
const calendar = google.calendar('v3');

const port = 3000;
const key = require('./credentials.json');
const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    key.client_email,
    null,
    key.private_key,
    [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
    null
);

jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Authorization worked!");
        console.log(tokens);
    }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    calendar.events.list({
        auth: jwtClient,
        calendarId: 'xxxx@resourcexxx.com',
        timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
        maxResults: 5,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime'
    }, function(err, resp) {
        res.json(resp);
    });
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(port, function(err){
    if (!err) {
        console.log("App is running on port", port);
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please edit your question and include your code and describe what issues you are having with that code

Comment: Hello Ann. Could you please: 1. Provide code that you have already used, in relation to the question you just created. 2. Describe precisely what data are you trying to get from your company's calendar. That would help us lots in knowing what answer to give. Thanks!

Comment: You're right. I edited the part and I have problems with the calendar.events.list method which doesn't work with resource calendars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm a non-admin user and as far as I know the service account has to impersonate a user. Do I need to be an admin user to manage and see the data of the resource calendar and share it with the service account?

- Service accounts **can** impersonate users, when they have domain-wide delegation enabled. It is not necessary.

  Service accounts behave like "normal" accounts - they have their own permissions on resources. That means that, if you want to get a specific calendar's data from that account, you will have to give it view permission. In case you would prefer to edit it using the service account, you will have to give the account edit permissions. You can do that as you would with any other user, the difference being that you will have to use the service account's e-mail address (which you will find in the developer's console) to reference it.

  If you are using service account that has domain-wide authentication enabled, when authenticating, you can specify a "subject" (an existing user of your domain) to impersonate. After a successful authentication, every action performed will be executed as if the "subject" account was the one performing them - and it will use that user's permissions.

> I use a jwtClient to authorize and I have no idea whether I have to use the Directory API, Google Calendar API or both to make it work.

- Since you are retrieving data from calendars (and not any user's information) you only need to use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference).

> What I want: retrieve the data of my company's resource calendar by using a service account with domain-wide delegation

- In your case - retrieving data - you can simply share that calendar with your service account. Afterwards, with no need to use domain-wide delegation, it will be able to use `calendar.events.list` to retrieve the events present in the calendar along with their details, using the same code you provided.

#### Reference

- [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference)
- [Performing domain-wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)